# javascript equivalent of jQuery's animate

Tags: javascript, jquery

First, here's the code snippet:

```
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(event) {

    var target = $( $(this).attr('href') );

    if( target.length ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('body').animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
    }

});
```

I am attempting to convert this into Javascript (since I do not yet know much in regards to jQuery).

And this is where I have reached so far:

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].addEventListener('click', function (event) {

        var target = document.getElementById(event.target.getAttribute('href'));
        if (target) {
            event.preventDefault();
            document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].animate({
                scrollTop: target.getBoundingClientRect().top
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
}
```

As you might have noticed, I am having problem in this section:

```
$('body').animate({
    scrollTop: target.offset().top
}, 1000);
```

What would be Javascript's alternative of `animate`? I know there's `setInterval` but I was wondering if there's a simpler way to achieve this?

Comment: jQuery is a JavaScript library, not a different programming language. If you want to know how jQuery animates stuff, then read jQuery's source code.

Comment: JavaScript animation == intervals. This is how jQuery animates behind the scenes. Your other option is to give/remove classes and handle the animations via CSS, though this isn't always viable depending on your criteria.

Comment: @Quentin I am aware that jQuery is basically JS library. And I infact did try what you said prior to posting this (The animate code is in effects.js: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/effects.js (if I am not wrong)). However, this does not mean that I can just pull out code and directly use it. I'll have to go through that whole hierarchy which is even more complicated and time consuming.

In any case, seems like using intervals is my only choice at the moment.